# Why does my TreeBuilder object not contain TreeBuilder's private attributes?

Tags: python, elementtree

When I instantiate an `xml.etree.ElementTree.TreeBuilder` object, I cannot see any of `TreeBuilder`'s private attributes.

```
Python 3.4.2 (v3.4.2:ab2c023a9432, Oct  6 2014, 22:15:05) on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>
>>> import xml.etree.ElementTree as etree
>>> etree.__file__
'C:\\Python34\\Lib\\xml\\etree\\ElementTree.py'
>>> b = etree.TreeBuilder()
>>> b._data
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'xml.etree.ElementTree.TreeBuilder' object has no attribute '_data'
>>>
```

even though `_data` should be there (excerpt from `C:\Python34\Lib\xml\etree\ElementTree.py`, line 1384):

```
def __init__(self, element_factory=None):
    self._data = [] # data collector
    self._elem = [] # element stack
    self._last = None # last element
    self._tail = None # true if we're after an end tag
    if element_factory is None:
        element_factory = Element
    self._factory = element_factory
```

## Goal

I want to subclass `TreeBuilder` to add support for an XML comment element, but need to get to one of the private attributes to append the comment element.